# How to set DirPagination pages number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using dirPagination for paging . i have dirPagination.js  dirPagination.tpl.html   and im using it in my htm pages like

```
dir-paginate="item in zeroized | orderBy : orderBy | filter:filterData | itemsPerPage: 10"
```

it works fine but i am going to make my application lazy loading in example on first request i will get only first pages data with count 10 then then i click to go on second page i will get next 10 objects and so on. If my total data's length is 54 i want to have 6 page and i will send request every click on next page. For now when i getting 10 object on first request my paggination gives me only 1 page . So can i set pages number myself ? P.S. I am using angular

Comment: i got solution i will set $scope.zeroized.length=51

Comment: There is a parameter in the documentation of [dir pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) please checkout the "total-items" section and the "Working With Asynchronous Data". It looks like what you need.